# getting error at pushviewcontroller in didSelectRowatIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am using continously UITableViewController type classes on didSelecRowAt IndexPath I need to display ViewController but it is giving following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the "videoView" nib
>   but didn't get a UITableView.'

the class declaration I am using as

```
@interface VideoCategory : UITableViewController
```

and

```
@interface videoView : UIViewController
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder you've got to set the File Owner of your nib file to your `VideoCategory` class. Then link the outlet `tableView` to a tableView in the nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Either you dont have declared a tableView outlet in your VideoCategory header file or have not connected this outlet to tableView in your nib file.

Comment: I already take UIViewController subclass with UITableviewcontroller type when I adding new file.Mean that nib file videocategory does not have UIview it have only UITableview.

Comment: I don't think I need to declare IBOutlet there whether I declare it as  @interface VideoCategory : UITableViewController and set file owner's view as tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

delete the app on simulator.
clean the project.
build and restart simulator.